# How do I restore a folder via GitKraken?

Tags: bitbucket, gitkraken

Somehow I've lost all the source code for my TacticalAILib. HOWEVER, when I look at GitKraken (see below) there the folder is:

[image]

But, when I got to the BitBucket repo there is no TacticalAILib source code. So my question is:

1. Where are these files that make up TacticalAILib folder that I'm seeing in GitKraken and
2. How can I restore them to my local computer?

Comment: The branch view of the repository would be much more helpful here. What commit are you looking at? The files have been merged in this commit, so they should exist in the repository, but we only know what happend to them if we see more commits and branches of the local and remote repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change to AIBranch and then double-click on it. Not exactly intuitive, but that's what worked. Found the answer on the GitKraken Slack forum.